# How to wait for tomcat restart before exit the Play in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am using handler to restart my tomcat if there is any configuration change happens. What i want to do is

1. Do a tomcat restart using handler
2. wait for it to be up and running
3. Once it is up then exit the Play and don't proceed further.

/roles/appconfig/task/main.yml -

```
 - name: Copying Application Configuration files to tomcat nodes
   template:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "{{config_location}}/{{ item | basename | regex_replace('.j2$', '') }}"
      mode: 0755
   with_fileglob:
    - /home/ansible/properties/dev/*.j2
   register: config_var
   notify: Restart tomcat
```

/roles/appconfig/handlers/main.yml -

```
---
 - block:
    - name: Restart service
      listen: "Restart tomcat"
      debug:
        msg: "Restarting tomcat as there are only configuration changes as a part of this Release."

    - name: Wait for tomcat start for 300 seconds and continue with play
      listen: "Restart tomcat"
      timeout: 10

## This is the way to check the tomcat status if it's online ##
    - name: Check the State of tomcat service on the remote host
      listen: "Restart tomcat"
      shell: "svcs tomcat"
      register: result

## task to check if tomcat started and register "tomcat_state"

    - name: End the play if tomcat returns status online
      listen: "Restart tomcat"
      meta: end_play
      when: result.stdout_lines.1.split().0 == "online"
   when: target_release_version == current_release
```

This is how I am restarting my tomcat in the handler. Now How do i wait for it to be up and running and then exit the Play.

Please advice.

Comment: You would need to create a script that will check the status of tomcat server. By hitting the URL if you get status response as 200 then you can exit the play otherwise you can fail the play

Comment: If you face any issue then let me know I could help you to achieve the same my friend :)

Comment: Updated the question with some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

Call handlers from your task. Handlers will be for restarting tomcat, wait, checking the status and finally to exit.

```
- name: Copying Application Configuration files to tomcat nodes
   ## Task to do, will notify handlers
   notify: "Restart tomcat"
```

Handlers file to have below :

```
# handlers file for tomcat_service_start_check
- name: Restart service
  listen: "Restart tomcat"
  shell: <script/command to start tomcat>

- name: Wait for tomcat start for N seconds and continue with play
  listen: "Restart tomcat"
  local_action:
    module: wait_for
      host={{ inventory_hostname }}
      port=8080
      delay=10

- name: Get tomcat status by hitting URL
  listen: "Restart tomcat"
  uri:
    url: http://localhost:8080
  register: tomcat_state

- name: End the play if tomcat returns HTTP 200
  listen: "Restart tomcat"
  meta: end_play
  when:
  - tomcat_state == '200'
```

Now, all handlers listen to "Restart tomcat". And once triggered, they will be executed in the order they are defined.

Reference :
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change

> Notify handlers are always run in the same order they are defined, not
>   in the order listed in the notify-statement. This is also the case for
>   handlers using listen.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried it but it gives me syntax error. Updated the handlers main.yml with your content and below is the output - ```ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'int'>
The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/roles/appconfig/handlers/main.yml': line 8, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
    - name: Wait for tomcat start for 300 seconds and continue with play
      ^ here```

Comment: I corrected the syntax, however, "timeout" is not supported in handlers. I will update the answer shortly.

Comment: Have updated handlers. This is working. Also note that, last handler "meta" will "skip" if tomcat is started, since we are ending the play.

Comment: Yes the listen module is life saver in Ansible. I have used above solution with some of my tweaks and it works fine. Thanks for the response